# Multiple Functions in Factories.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
 function CadError($http) {

    // Return the object
    return {

        // Create simple method to get data from $http service
        getFullList : function() {
            return $http({

                url: 'URL',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        }
        
    }

}

function LogError($http) {

    // Return the object
    return {

        // Create simple method to get data from $http service
        getFullList : function() {
            return $http({
                url: 'URL',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        }
    }

    }

    angular
        .module('inspinia')
        .factory('CadError', CadError);
```

I am wondering how to implement two data sets in a single factories.js file. I am able to load the first data set called cad error but I have not been able to load the second set log error data. I had added another line at the bottom `.factory('LogErrorData',LogErrorData);`

However that broke the first cad error so I removed it. Any help would be appreciated. If you need more code I can provide that.

#### Update

**controller.js**

```
function caderror($scope, CadError) {

    // Run method getFullList() from factory
    myFac.getFullList().success(function(data){

        // Assign data to $scope
        $scope.dataFromFactory = data;
    });

}
function logerror($scope, LogError) {

    // Run method getFullList() from factory
    myFac.getFullList().success(function(data){

        // Assign data to $scope
        $scope.dataFromFactory = data;
    });

}
```

Comment: Take a look for an updated ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular
     .module('inspinia')
     .factory('myFac', function($http){
     return {
        CadError : function() {
            return {
               // Create simple method to get data from $http service
               getFullList : function() {
                   return $http({url: 'URL',method: 'GET'})
               }
              }
        },
        LogError: function() {
           return {
             getFullList : function() {
                return $http({url: 'URL',method: 'GET'})
               }
            }
         }
    }
  });
```

**CONTROLLER.JS**

```
function caderror($scope, myFac) {

    // Run method getFullList() from factory
    myFac.CadError().getFullList().success(function(data){

        // Assign data to $scope
        $scope.dataFromFactory = data;
    });

}
function logerror($scope, myFac) {

    // Run method getFullList() from factory
    myFac.LogError().getFullList().success(function(data){

        // Assign data to $scope
        $scope.dataFromFactory = data;
    });

}
```

Comment: @GoldenWest : You'll inject `myFac` to the controller where it'll called

Comment: I can post the html page as well if needed

Comment: hmmm still not able to load the data anything else i could do to help shed more light?

Comment: @GoldenWest : are you getting  the value in `$scope.dataFromFactory` from my code ? Try to create a plunkr and show me what you are trying to achieve. I'll fix it in a min then. **PS**: use `$scope.dataFromFactory = response.data` as you are returning `$http` itself. check my ctrl update again

Comment: @GoldenWest : You havent even put an effort to add `angular.js` file. You dont have any working code and html. You need to put some effort before asking mine. Also, please delete some unnecessary comments against my answer or let move this discussion to chat as the list of comment is growing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169356/discussion-between-goldenwest-and-shashank-vivek).

Comment: hmmm your code submitted throws a syntax error when reviewed from the console.

Comment: @GoldenWest : Cheers mate !